# What word can I use as the opposite of "artistic" in university contexts?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

Work at the university is generally divided into on the one hand artistic work, and, on the other hand, work based on scholarly research, right? Now I need an adjective for the non-artistic kind of work. My bilingual dictionary suggests *disciplinary*, but it sounds a bit odd to my ears, and when I look it up in monolingual English dictionaries (Cambridge, Merriam-Webster and Longman), I find no support at all for this use of *disciplinary*.

So, am I right in assuming that *disciplinary* doesn't work in this context, and, if so, what word should I use instead?

Comment: Maybe, *technical*.

Comment: As a former university employee, I would say it is divided into _sciences_ and _humanities_ (a broader term than _arts_, including literature, philosophy etc.)

Comment: An abbreviation which has come into wide use recently in the UK is STEM subjects (science, technology, engineering and mathematics) which may or may not fit your need case.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Yes, I see what you mean, but I think that would rather apply to the distinction between the sciences and the humanities, which Kate Bunting mentions too? I'm after the distinction between on the one hand all the subjects that fall under sciences + all the "non-artistic" subjects within the humanities, and, on the other hand artistic subject (i.e. the fine and performing arts)

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, there is that distinction too – however, what I'm after is rather the distinction between subjects that fall within the fine and performing arts, and subjects that don't (see also my response to Jack above). But perhaps that's not a distinction that is made outside my own country... Either way, would you agree that "disciplinary" doesn't really work?

Comment: @mdewey Interesting! Still, it's not really that distinction I'm after, but rather the distinction between the fine and performing arts and all other subjects.

Comment: I'm not aware of that distinction being made here (UK). _Disciplinary_ suggests the enforcement of rules rather than a group of subjects.

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting that, at least in the UK, we do not have an umbrella term for performing arts + fine arts. Now you mention it there does seem to be a gap in our language

Comment: @KateBunting Right – my thoughts exactly! Thanks for confirming :)

Comment: @mdewey Haha, yeah – there are a few of them (gaps, I mean). Then again – not half as many as there are in my own language :)

Comment: Would https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_industries help? It seems to have the right coverage but is about the world outside universities.

Comment: @mdewey Thank you for really trying to help me with this! It is, however, the distinction specifically made in a university context I need though. But no worries – I'll just rephrase a bit; what's important to me is that I stick with what's commonly accepted in Englisg – that is, I don't want to rephrase if there is indeed a specific word, and, the other way round: I don't want to use a specific word (such as, for instance, *disciplinary*) in the wrong way :)

Comment: @Helen Just out of curiosity, what is your native language and what are the words in it that describe the dichotomy you refer to?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty My native language is Swedish, and we use the words *vetenskaplig* (which in other contexts would translate as *scientific*, *academic* or *scholarly*) and *konstnärlig* (which translates as *artistic*). Come to think of it, perhaps *academic* would work even in this context? Would that make sense? To divide work at the university into academic and artistic work?

Comment: @Helen I think studying art and performance at university might also be called *academic* work. Maybe it will take more than two words to draw the distinction you want to make.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Ok, thanks – I'll just rephrase then :)